# Regex Pattern In Between Two Exact Strings

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have this working code to detect a valid UUID pattern.

```java
String pattern = "\\b[a-f0-9]{8}\\b-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-\\b[a-f0-9]{12}\\b";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(fileName);
```

This correctly detects strings like:

`0101a8ef-db10-405a-a1d2-6bebdeb17625`

I would like to add two exact strings on each side of this pattern like so:

`FOLDER/0101a8ef-db10-405a-a1d2-6bebdeb17625.txt`

Here is the code I am trying, but is not working:

```java
String pattern = "FOLDER/\\b//[a-f0-9]{8}\\b-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-\\b[a-f0-9]{12}\\b.txt";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(uri.toString());
```

Comment: What's the point of `\b`?

Comment: Why not like `FOLDER/[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}\\.txt` https://regex101.com/r/CJjLUP/1

Comment: @shmosel Not sure, it was part of the code example that I got the first pattern from.

Comment: @Thefourthbird this works, thanks! You should add an answer to this post for future reference.

Comment: [UUID.fromString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html#fromString(java.lang.String)) already does this check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `//` in the pattern that is not in the example string. Besides that, you can omit the word boundaries in between a character a-f0-9 and a `-` because it is implicit.

Note to escape the dot to match it literally, and you can add the word boundaries at the start and at the end to prevent partial matches.

You could update the pattern to

```
\\bFOLDER/[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}\\.txt\\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q9cpLt/1).